# Bigquery unnest minimum number of rows

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I am trying to write a unnest query along with limit. When I use unnest, it gives me duplicate entries for other columns, which is expected, but is there a way I can specify I want to have minimum of 10 unique records of a particular column?

this is my sample data and query

```
food.id                     STRING  NULLABLE    
food.basket.id              STRING  NULLABLE
food.foodType               STRING  NULLABLE
food.price                  INTEGER NULLABLE    
food.printed                BOOLEAN NULLABLE    
food.variations             RECORD  REPEATED    
food.variations.id          INTEGER REPEATED    
food.variations.amount      INTEGER NULLABLE
```

Sample data

```
id     basket.id.    foodType.    price.    printed.    variations.id      variations.amount
1.      abbcd.         JUNK.       100.       TRUE.        1234.            10
                                                           2345.            20
2.      cdefg.         PIZZA.      200.       TRUE.        1234.            10
                                                           2345.            20
                                                           5678.            20
                                                           7816.            40
3.      pqrst.         JUNK.       200.       FALSE.       1234.            10
                                                           2345.            20
                                                           5678.            20
                                                           7816.            40
4.      uiwka.         TOAST.      500.       FALSE.       1234.            10
                                                           9898.            20
                                                           5678.            20
                                                           7816.            40
```

This is my sample query:

```
select basket.id as bId, foodType, price, printed, v.id as vId, v.amount as vAmount from my_table_name left join UNNEST (variations) as v limit 10;
```

this is the result:

```
id       bId.        foodType.    price.    printed.       vId.           vAmount
1.      abbcd.         JUNK.       100.       TRUE.        1234.            10
2.      abbcd.         JUNK.       100.       TRUE.        2345.            20
3.      cdefg.         PIZZA.      200.       TRUE.        1234.            10
4.      cdefg.         PIZZA.      200.       TRUE.        2345.            20
5.      cdefg.         PIZZA.      200.       TRUE.        5678.            20
6.      cdefg.         PIZZA.      200.       TRUE.        7816.            40
7.      pqrst.         JUNK.       200.       FALSE.       1234.            10
8.      pqrst.         JUNK.       200.       FALSE.       2345.            20
9.      pqrst.         JUNK.       200.       FALSE.       5678.            20
10.     pqrst.         JUNK.       200.       FALSE.       7816.            40
```

so now my row with bId `uiwka` went missing. 
So I am trying to write a query which will give me a limit on the number of unique bId's I get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply move you `LIMIT` a little up - as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  basket.id AS bId, 
  foodType, price, 
  printed, 
  v.id AS vId, 
  v.amount AS vAmount 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` LIMIT 10)
LEFT JOIN UNNEST (variations) AS v
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. :)